# how to put keys in a for loop in react

Tags: reactjs, list, loops, key, unique-key

I have a key problem in my condition in react with a for loop, it gives me a warning

I inserted my keys correctly, however I think but i have : "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." error

```js
    //Création des boutons
    const buttons = [];
    
    for (const page of pageNumbers) {
        //if page is first or endPage
        if (page === 1 || page === totalPages) {
            buttons.push(
                <>
                    <li
                        key={"1"}
                        className={`page-item ${
                            currentPage == page ? "active" : ""
                        }`}
                    >
                        <Button
                            className="page-link btnPaginate btn btn-link"
                            variant="link"
                            value={page}
                            onClick={() => props.handlePaginate(page)}
                        >
                            {page}
                        </Button>
                    </li>
                </>
            );
        }
        //if page is not first or not endPage
        else if (page >= currentPage - 1 && page <= currentPage + 1) {
            buttons.push(
                <>
                    <li
                        key={"2"}
                        className={`page-item ${
                            currentPage == page ? "active" : ""
                        }`}
                    >
                        <Button
                            className="page-link btnPaginate btn btn-link"
                            variant="link"
                            value={page}
                            onClick={() => props.handlePaginate(page)}
                        >
                            {page}
                        </Button>
                    </li>
                </>
            );
        }
        //show left dots 
        else if (showDotsLeft && page === 2) {
            buttons.push(
                <>
                    <li
                        key={"3"}
                        className={`page-item ${
                            currentPage == page ? "active" : ""
                        }`}
                    >
                        <Button
                            className="page-link btnDotsLeft btn btn-link"
                            variant="link"
                            key="dots-left"
                        >
                            ...
                        </Button>
                    </li>
                </>
            );
        }
        //show right dots
        else if (showDotsRight && page === currentPage + 2) {
            buttons.push(
                <>
                    <li
                        key={"4"}
                        className={`page-item ${
                            currentPage == page ? "active" : ""
                        }`}
                    >
                        <Button
                            className="page-link btnDotsRight btn btn-link"
                            variant="link"
                        >
                            ...
                        </Button>
                    </li>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

I inserted my keys correctly, however I think but i have : "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop." error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `key` needs to be added into the top level element.

In your example you have a `React.Fragment` as a top level element instead of the `<li>` you added the key into.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a key to each child **as well as each element inside children**.

This way React can handle all the minimal DOM changes,

So you need to set `key` prop for each `<Button />` too!

Comment: thanks for the reply. So I have to put keys on the <li> and on the <Button>?

Comment: Yes, and it would be better not to use React Fragments in your example.

Comment: Solution trouvée...
<React.Fragment key={page}>
                    <li
                        key="1"
                        className={`page-item ${
                            currentPage == page ? "active" : ""
                        }`}
                    >

Answer (score 0):

solution found... Use <React.Fragment key={page}> rather than <>

```js
<React.Fragment key={page}>
                    <li
                        key="1"
                        className={`page-item ${
                            currentPage == page ? "active" : ""
                        }`}
                    >
                        <Button
                            key="2"
                            className="page-link btnPaginate btn btn-link"
                            variant="link"
                            value={page}
                            onClick={() => props.handlePaginate(page)}
                        >
                            {page}
                        </Button>
                    </li>
                </React.Fragment>
```

Thanks for your comments and aids